# ViewParam and session scoped bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I defined `viewParam` to process a `GET` request but the session bean is `null`.

```
/treeTable2.xhtml @28,119 value="#{conformanceProfileController.dataValueAssertionController.library_line}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'conformanceProfileController' resolved to null
```

**`GET` request:**

```
treeTable2.jsf?category=Message
```

**XHTML code**

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="category" value="#{conformanceProfileController.category}" />
</f:metadata>
```

**The Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ConformanceProfileController implements Serializable {
    private String category;

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

My development server is `Tomcat 7.0` and I use `Mojarra 2.1.0`

**EDIT**: I created a simplified version with a new page and new bean. The code in the post is the same as the one on my machine.

**XHTML Code:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    >
<h:head>
</h:head>
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="category" value="#{myBean.category}" />
</f:metadata>
<h:body>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**MyBean:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private String category;

    public MyBean() {
        System.out.println("Creation");
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

}
```

**The GET request**: `treeTable3.jsf?category=Message`

**The error message:** `/treeTable3.xhtml @8,60 value="#{myBean.category}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'myBean' resolved to null`

Comment: Should work fine. Didn't you edit/oversimplify the error message or the `f:viewParam`? Sounds like if you're trying to set a view param on a nested property which is actually `null`.

Comment: The error is the original one. I created a new page replicating the issue, but I still got the issue. I also added a constructor to see if it's actually called, and obviously it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mojarra 2.1.0 [do not work](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.1.0/issues.html) in Tomcat/Jetty due to [a bug](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1937) in annotation scanning. Upgrade to at least 2.1.1 or the [current](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) 2.1.3.

This has nothing to do with view parameters or session scoped beans. It will just fail in all cases where you expect a `@ManagedBean`.

Comment: I created a new example to make sure it was not a problem of nested property.

Answer (score 0):

Give the @Named annotation a try: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbak.html

Comment: Can you please elaborate in more technical detail why you think that this would make difference? Otherwise I'm inclined to downvote the answer as "Random guessing and stabbing in the dark". Better post a comment then.

Comment: Not a random guess. I've run into NPE's before that were solved with the @Named annotation.

Comment: Well Ok, I now see the cause.